# Saving multiple users data in database in shiny

Tags: r

I am trying to save my shiny app form information from different users in the database. But for single user only, I am getting multiple rows for single form only. I want only one row per user information.
Th screen shot of the database filled can be seen below- it is single user data-

I am using -

[image]

I am using this in R

```
dbWriteTable(mydb, value = mydf(), name = 'table name', row.names=FALSE, append=T,
overwrite=F)
```

Comment: how `mydf()` looks like?

Comment: my df is a reactive dataframe. It is saving every event's data. Like. Name, country. etc.